# Installing Package Using NPM from Private Repository

Tags: node.js, npm

What is the correct syntax in "package.json" so I can install a package from a private npm repository.

My repository is running sinopia at http://localhost:4873 and I have a package called "foo".  I can upload without issue

I want something like this in my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "y",
  ...
  "dependencies": {
      "foo": "http://localhost:4873/"
  },
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I am not able to do this by way of package.json.  The most I can do is preregister the server:

```
 npm set registry <server>
```

Then npm will find my packages as necessary

Answer (score 2):

You can also set it in your project if you create a .npmrc file with `registry=http://your_registry` in your project from where you do your `npm install`